# Displayport won't work after powering on until I reconnect it

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, kde, intel

Been searching online for a couple hours, but I've tried everything that I can find so far to no avail.

I've been using Kubuntu on my Thinkpad (Intel integrated graphics) and it was working perfectly fine. Eventually, something I did uninstalled my desktop environment (KDE) by accident. I reinstalled everything via TTY1 with no problems.

Now, my 2nd monitor (displayport) wont display anything when I power on until I unplug the displayport and plug it back in. After that, it works fine until I turn the pc off again.

So far I've tried:
Updating everything including drivers,
Reinstalling kubuntu-desktop, X, and SDDM,
Switching to autorandr instead of kscreen,
and finally, reinstalling Kubuntu entirely.

Thanks for your help.